# Assigned users to see only assigned data (Admin Panel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a scenario where I have different types of Roles such as
 SuperAdmin = 0

Admin = 1

Users = 2

What I want is,

*There is a dropdownlist which has several Organisations name each one of them is related to admins and users.*

*Now, when any user or admin logs in to the panel he should be able to view only the organisation name which is related to him and that too in Readonly property.*

*I Have created the table, now I can see the all the organisations in the dropdownlist as per requirement of SuperAdmin.*

I have created two tables one for User and second CompanyName and have created a relation between them. Now what i want is

The query when User is logged in he should be able to view only the organisation name related to him in the dropdownlist

Hi,

I have a scenario where I have different types of Roles such as SuperAdmin, Admin and Users.

What I want is,

There is a dropdownlist which has several Organisations name each one of them is related to admins and users.

Now, when any user or admin logs in to the panel he should be able to view only the organisation name which is related to him and that too in Readonly property.

I Have created the table, now I can see the all the organisations in the dropdownlist as per requirement of SuperAdmin.

I have created two tables one for User and second CompanyName and have created a relation between them. Now what i want is

The query when User is logged in he should be able to view only the organisation name related to him in the dropdownlist

My dropdownlist code is

```
private void BindDropdownlist()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_ngoname", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);



        ddlngonameselect.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Id"].ToString();
        ddlngonameselect.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ngo_name"].ToString();
        ddlngonameselect.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlngonameselect.DataBind();
        ddlngonameselect.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Show All--", "0"));

    }
```

Also see the usertype for each user.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", md5(txtPassword.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", 1);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "0") //SuperAdmin
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "0";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "1") // Admin
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "1";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "2") // User
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "2";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after researching and debugging, I have got my own answer.

Here I go:-

```
private void BindDropdownlist()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                tempUsertype = Convert.ToString(Session["UserType"]);
                if (tempUsertype != string.Empty)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand((tempUsertype == "0" ? "Select * from tbl_ngoname" : "Select * from tbl_ngoname where id in (Select NgoId from tbl_User where username=@username)"), conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        ddlngonameselect.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Id"].ToString();
                        ddlngonameselect.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ngo_name"].ToString();
                        ddlngonameselect.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        ddlngonameselect.SelectedIndex = 0;

                        if (Session["UserType"] == "1" || Session["UserType"] == "2")
                        {
                            ddlngonameselect.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ddlngonameselect.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "--Select NGO--", Value = "0" });
                            ddlngonameselect.Enabled = true;
                        }

                        ddlngonameselect.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Some error");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

I tried this and it worked for me :)